# How to add ssh keys to a specific user in linux?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and we have an admin account and an account for other users. I have added the  public SSH keys of users who need admin access to the admin account, but when I try to do the same for an individual user, I don't see the `authorized_keys` file in `.ssh` directory for that user. How should I proceed here?

The below are the commands that I have tried:

```
cd /home
cd /admin
ls -a
nano .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then I add the public key to the admin account. This works for admin but for other users I can't see any `authorized_keys` file.

Comment: if it doesn't exist just create it.  It's just a plain text file; no special magic.  Set perms  like `chmod go-rwx` if your umask is too loose.

Comment: everyone's umask is too loose and you know it.  Just chmod go-rwx it and make sur eit's owned by the user, not by root if you were root when you crated it.  ssh is especially picky about permissions on this file.  You MIGHT also need to consider selinux context depending on how it gets created (by hand or by script running non-interactively)

Answer (score 14):

Generate an ssh key:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "comment"
```

copy it to your remote server:

```
ssh-copy-id user@ip
```

or you can manually append the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`:

```
ssh user@ip 'mkdir ~/.ssh'
ssh user@ip 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys' < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: "or you can manually copy the ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys" -- For those new to doing that, if you interpret this literally and scp the file, you'd remove key access of other users. You want to **append** your key to the file, not copy over it. When `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` doesn't exist, it doesn't make a difference for the first, but it does for each subsequent one.

Comment: Rather than `scp`, use `ssh user@ip 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys' < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, so that you don't need to worry about whether or not there is already an authorized keys file.

Comment: @GAD3R I think you didn't understand my point. I was recommending against doing that. I predict there'll be people that'll take that `scp` command as an alternative to `ssh-copy-id` without understanding the limited circumstance in which it's acceptable.

Comment: Better than to append an ID manually, one can specify an ID file to `ssh-copy-id` using the `-i` option: `ssh-copy-id -i path/to/id_rsa user@host` (`.pub` is appended if missing). This will create missing directories (`~/.ssh`) and files (`authorized_keys`) *with the appropriate access mode*.

Answer (score 6):

The file is created when you run `ssh-copy-id <user>@<server>`, for example:

```
sylvester@host3:~> ssh-copy-id arnold@host4
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/sylvester/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
Password: 

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'arnold@host4'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

The file is not present yet because noone has added anything for this user.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need any particular tool to create the authorized keys file, or to tell any particular programs that it exists. `sshd` will look for it each time the user tries to log in.

So quite simply, if it doesn't exist, you can create it the same way you were editing the existing file for a different user.

What you *do* need to do is make sure the permissions are sufficiently locked down, otherwise `sshd` will refuse to trust the file. So the steps to create in a completely empty home directory for user `joebloggs` would look something like this:

```
# Create the .ssh directory, and set its permissions
mkdir ~joebloggs/.ssh
chown joebloggs ~joebloggs/.ssh
chmod 0700 ~joebloggs/.ssh

# Create the authorized keys file, and set its permissions
touch ~joebloggs/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown joebloggs ~joebloggs/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 0600 ~joebloggs/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

This creates a completely empty `.ssh/authorized_keys` file, which only `joebloggs` can access, read, and write.

This is the *minimum* permission required, following the principle of least privilege. If you want, you can allow read-only access to a particular group (`chgrp -R some-group ~joebloggs/.ssh; chmod 750 ~joebloggs/.ssh; chmod 640 ~joebloggs/.ssh/authorized_keys`), or to all users on the system (`chmod 755 ~joebloggs/.ssh; chmod 644 ~joebloggs/.ssh/authorized_keys`). The important thing is that they must not be able to *write* to it, or the SSH daemon will not trust its contents.

Comment: Permissions for authorized keys is supposed to be 644 and the chown commands need to add permission for the user and group to own it not just the user. I am using Redhat/Amazon Linux for reference.

Comment: @Tony-Caffe I can't think of any reason for anybody other than the user logging in to read the file, so no need for any group or "other" permissions; and if there's no group permissions, it doesn't matter which group owns the file. The only thing I have changed looking back at this is that the file doesn't need to be executable, so can be 0600 (rw----) rather than 0700 (rwx------).

Comment: @Tony-Caffe I've added a note that it doesn't *hurt* to allow other users to read the file; if you know of a specific scenario where a user other than the owner *needs* to, and can clarify *which* user, I will add that.

Answer (score 1):

1. `ssh-keygen` (press enter / do not enter any passwords)
2. `ssh-keyscan hpc.university.edu > known_hosts` (press enter)
3. `ssh-copy-id yourname@hpc.university.edu` ( press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) you might need some password to go through university VPN in this case , you can enter them )